# pass variables to jade template

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, parameter-passing, pug

I am trying to pass variables from page.js to page.jade but for some reason this is not working.

here's my code:

page.js

```
res.render('page', {param1: 'xxx', param2: 'yyy'} );
```

page.jade

```
#{param1}
br
#{param2}
br
```

Comment: Can you elaborate more? How is `page.jade` receiving the `res` object from `page.js`, let alone the `param1` and `param2` variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be rendering them as tags instead. View your source html post render.

Try using !{param} instead of #{param}.

Comment: as Ned Flanders will say in spanish: "perfectirijillo!!" 
thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Try passing your variables like this

```
res.render('page', {params: {param1: 'xxx', param2: 'yyy'}});
```

And inside your template

```
#{params.param1}
```

Comment: can you elaborate on this? why like this?

Comment: in the jade template the whole data is present as object via params variable, so params.param1 would get the value for param1. Interpolating that value requires use of #{} tag format while appending the value to a string. Else u can use somthing like: p= params.param1 directly too